# Building PJSIP for iOS 4

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, osx-lion, pjsip

I am attempting to build the latest stable PJSIP (1.10) for the iPhone and I am running into some errors during my `make`. I've followed the instructions [here](http://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/iPhone), but I am not having any luck. I searched around SO and google and haven't run into anyone else with the same error, so I am a bit stuck.

I've created my `config_site.h` as instructed. `./configure-iphone` gives the output I've seen elsewhere, so that portion seems to be working correctly. `make dep` seems to be working correctly, as does `make clean`, but I get the following error on my `make` (which should be the final step before getting an `Xcode` project I can work with, by my reading at least).

```
if test ! -d ../bin; then mkdir -p ../bin; fi
/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/arm-apple-darwin10-gcc-4.2.1 -o ../bin/pjlib-util-test-arm-apple-darwin9 \
         output/pjlib-util-test-arm-apple-darwin9/main.o  output/pjlib-util-test-arm-apple-darwin9/xml.o  output/pjlib-util-test-arm-apple-darwin9/encryption.o  output/pjlib-util-test-arm-apple-darwin9/stun.o  output/pjlib-util-test-arm-apple-darwin9/resolver_test.o  output/pjlib-util-test-arm-apple-darwin9/test.o  output/pjlib-util-test-arm-apple-darwin9/http_client.o ../lib/libpjlib-util-arm-apple-darwin9.a /pjproject-1.10/pjlib/lib/libpj-arm-apple-darwin9.a  -O2  -isysroot /Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS4.3.sdk -framework AudioToolbox -framework Foundation -luuid -lpthread  -framework CoreAudio -framework CoreFoundation -framework AudioToolbox -framework CFNetwork -framework UIKit    
ld: library not found for -luuid
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [../bin/pjlib-util-test-arm-apple-darwin9] Error 1
make[1]: *** [pjlib-util-test] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

I am running on OS X 10.7.1 with Xcode 4.1 (I've got the beta for iOS 5 installed as well, but the make output doesn't appear to be referencing its folder at all from what I can tell).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure specifically what caused this, but I was able to work around it by building the app on a fresh OS X Lion install with nothing but Xcode 4.1 installed.